# sql select condition, if col1 empty check on col2

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, ifnull

How could I achieve the following in SQL. (I have trouble with the checking if `col1` is empty, check if `col2` is `"confirmed"`)

`select data from table1 where col1 = "true"` or (if `col1` is empty, check `col2 = "confirmed"`).

(the value to check for `col1` and `col2` are different)

Comment: Opps ... I am using sqlite.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming col2 is non-null. If it can be `null`, expand the conditions (similar to the one shown)

```
where (col1 is not null and col1='true')
or (col1 is null and col2='confirmed')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I tried it with sqlite, It doesn't work. It only take the first condition. the output is only all the data with col1 not null and equal to col1='true'.

Comment: My full statement is as below: select name, date from table1 where (col1 is not null and lower(col1) = 'true' ) OR (col1is null and lower(col2) = 'confirmed') ;

Comment: I just found out  from SQL doc. ............The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL, then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not, then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is 1 (true). It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to evaluate to NULL. Operators IS and IS NOT have the same precedence as =.

Comment: Any other option!!